# Рop-up при загрузке главной страницы

Tags: jquery, joomla

Привет!

Никогда с жумлой дела не имел, а тут пришла такая задача - при загрузке хоумпейджа должен показываться попап (два дива: фон+само окно, внутри картинка)
Попап я сделал, жкверями его настроил.

Теперь сама задача - каким способом лучше всего прикрутить это дело в админку жумлы - чтобы я могу включать/выключать этот попап время от времени, и мог заменять картинку в нем.
По большому счету мне просто нужно как-то реализовать включение-выключение вывода пары строчек кода с визивигом?

Спасибо!

Joomla 1.5.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш поп-ап необходимо реализовать в виде расширения joomla. А лучше воспользуйтесь готовыми расширениями на [JED](http://extensions.joomla.org/). Конкретное расширение не помню как называется - делал давно...

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ, буду искать что-то готовое

Comment: Да, готовый модуль отлично справился с этим! Спасибо!